# pip2 not updating package to latest version

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I'm attempting to update the PRAW package with `pip2` from 2.1.3 to the latest (2.1.4) but for some reason after finding version 2.1.4 it proceeds to install 2.1.3 again.

```
% pip2 search praw             
praw                      - PRAW, an acronym for `Python Reddit API Wrapper`, is a python      package that allows for simple access to reddit's API.
  INSTALLED: 2.1.3
  LATEST:    2.1.4
```

Here's the verbose log. I've tried doing `-U`, `--update` and `sudo pip2 install praw==2.1.4`

```
Downloading/unpacking praw==2.1.4
  Running setup.py egg_info for package praw
    running egg_info
    writing requirements to pip-egg-info/praw.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing pip-egg-info/praw.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/praw.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/praw.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing entry points to pip-egg-info/praw.egg-info/entry_points.txt
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    reading manifest file 'pip-egg-info/praw.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/praw.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  Requested praw==2.1.4, but installing version 2.1.3
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests>=1.2.0 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from praw==2.1.4)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from praw==2.1.4)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): update-checker>=0.5 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from praw==2.1.4)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from update-checker>=0.5->praw==2.1.4)
Installing collected packages: praw
  Found existing installation: praw 2.1.3
    Uninstalling praw:
      Removing file or directory /usr/bin/praw-multiprocess
      Removing file or directory /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw-2.1.3-py2.7.egg-info
      Removing file or directory /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw/__init__.py
      Removing file or directory /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw/__init__.pyc
      Removing file or directory /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw/decorators.py
      Removing file or directory /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw/decorators.pyc
      Removing file or directory /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw/errors.py
      Removing file or directory /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw/errors.pyc
      Removing file or directory /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw/handlers.py
      Removing file or directory /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw/handlers.pyc
      Removing file or directory /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw/helpers.py
      Removing file or directory /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw/helpers.pyc
      Removing file or directory /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw/internal.py
      Removing file or directory /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw/internal.pyc
      Removing file or directory /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw/multiprocess.py
      Removing file or directory /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw/multiprocess.pyc
      Removing file or directory /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw/objects.py
      Removing file or directory /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw/objects.pyc
      Removing file or directory /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw/praw.ini
      Removing file or directory /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw/settings.py
      Removing file or directory /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw/settings.pyc
      Removing file or directory /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw/tests/__init__.py
      Removing file or directory /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw/tests/__init__.pyc
      Successfully uninstalled praw
  Running setup.py install for praw
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    running install_lib
    creating /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw
    copying build/lib/praw/praw.ini -> /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw
    creating /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw/tests
    copying build/lib/praw/tests/__init__.py -> /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw/tests
    copying build/lib/praw/internal.py -> /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw
    copying build/lib/praw/__init__.py -> /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw
    copying build/lib/praw/objects.py -> /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw
    copying build/lib/praw/handlers.py -> /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw
    copying build/lib/praw/decorators.py -> /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw
    copying build/lib/praw/settings.py -> /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw
    copying build/lib/praw/errors.py -> /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw
    copying build/lib/praw/multiprocess.py -> /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw
    copying build/lib/praw/helpers.py -> /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw
    byte-compiling /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw/tests/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
    byte-compiling /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw/internal.py to internal.pyc
    byte-compiling /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
    byte-compiling /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw/objects.py to objects.pyc
    byte-compiling /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw/handlers.py to handlers.pyc
    byte-compiling /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw/decorators.py to decorators.pyc
    byte-compiling /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw/settings.py to settings.pyc
    byte-compiling /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw/errors.py to errors.pyc
    byte-compiling /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw/multiprocess.py to multiprocess.pyc
    byte-compiling /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw/helpers.py to helpers.pyc
    running install_egg_info
    running egg_info
    writing requirements to praw.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing praw.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to praw.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to praw.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing entry points to praw.egg-info/entry_points.txt
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    reading manifest file 'praw.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    writing manifest file 'praw.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    Copying praw.egg-info to /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/praw-2.1.3-py2.7.egg-info
    running install_scripts
    Installing praw-multiprocess script to /usr/bin
    writing list of installed files to '/tmp/pip-NKy2i9-record/install-record.txt'
Successfully installed praw
Cleaning up...
```

This is on Arch Linux running Python 2.7.5.

Comment: No idea why this would happen, but have you tried uninstalling it and then re-installing it? `pip uninstall praw` then `pip install praw`

Comment: Pip2 is in experimental stage. Why can't you use just pip? Any specific reasons for that you use `pip2`?

Comment: I'm using `pip2` because it's for a python2 script, I tried uninstalling and installing again and got 2.1.3. And pip does the same, `pip` installs the old version (after removing the same old version).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You likely have a stale build directory laying around. This is made better with pip 1.4 but to fix your problem you just need to delete it. It should be located inside the root of the virtualenv if you're using one. Or in /tmp/ if you're not.

Comment: Oh thanks! It was exactly `sudo rm -rf /tmp/pip-build-$USER /tmp/pip-build-root` that fixed it. Perfect!